# Move a div inside another div depending on random dice roll?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am trying to develop a simple Monopoly style game. I am very new to JavaScript, but i would like to move the game piece around the board. or move it from the starting div into another div depending on the dice roll. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<div>
        <div class="row">
            <div data-type="recharge" class="board-square">
                <img src="assets/images/eco-friendly-sign.jpg">
                <div id="peice-one"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-type="city-garden" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="earthship" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="hydroponics" class="board-square"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div data-type="ev-car" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="greenway" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="cycle-path" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="greenspace" class="board-square"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div data-type="hydroelectric" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="solar-farm" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="community-work" class="board-square"></div>
            <div data-type="habitat-survey" class="board-square"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
let peiceOne = document.getElementById('peice-one');
let squares = document.getElementsByClassName('board-square');
function movePeices() {

    let diceRoll = rollDice();
    console.log(diceRoll);

    //target the divs to move number of spaces as diceRoll
    for (let square of squares) {
        let squareName = square.getAttribute('data-type');
    }

    peiceOne.appendChild(squares[diceRoll]);

}
```

Edit

This has helped it moves the div, but not on every dice roll.

```
// Declare a fragment:
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Append desired element to the fragment:
fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById('source'));

// Append fragment to desired element:
document.getElementById('destination').appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are appending the values instead of moving the piece. Try this:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div data-type="recharge" class="board-square">
            <img src="assets/images/eco-friendly-sign.jpg">
            <div id="piece-one"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-type="city-garden" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="earthship" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="hydroponics" class="board-square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div data-type="ev-car" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="greenway" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="cycle-path" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="greenspace" class="board-square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div data-type="hydroelectric" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="solar-farm" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="community-work" class="board-square"></div>
        <div data-type="habitat-survey" class="board-square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
let pieceOne = document.getElementById('piece-one');
let squares = document.getElementsByClassName('board-square');
let currentPosition = 0;
const board = [
    'recharge',
    'city-garden',
    'earthship',
    'hydroponics',
    'ev-car',
    'greenway',
    'cycle-path',
    'greenspace',
    'hydroelectric',
    'solar-farm',
    'community-work',
    'habitat-survey'
];

function rollDice() {
    // return a random number between 1 and 6
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}

function movePiece() {
    let diceRoll = rollDice();
    currentPosition += diceRoll;
    if (currentPosition >= board.length) {
        currentPosition -= board.length;
    }
    let currentSquare = squares[currentPosition];
    currentSquare.appendChild(pieceOne);
}
```